# span and anchor position display issue - Inside li tag

Tags: html, css, anchor, display

I have the below fiddle which displays correctly span and anchor tags in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. in IE, anchor element is coming below.

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/h2t1btfg/4/

**HTML**

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
  <span class="menu-item view-all prefix ">No Results</span>
  <a tabindex="-1" class="menu-item view-all ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-4">View All?</a>
</li>
```

What I wanted to achieve is to have "No Results" and "View All" to align in single row. But IE is displaying "View All" incorrectly.

Comment: I am not sure from your description what you are wanting this to do.  Could you please be more clear as to what you are expecting?

Comment: Edited with more details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. **Also**, anchors have `href` attributes.....if you don't add that you get non-normative behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor element is set to `display: block;` and you are probably looking for `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

see if that is what you want to do.

[jsfiddle.net/ywtausv3/](https://jsfiddle.net/ywtausv3/)

```
.ui-menu-item {
    min-height: 33px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu-item.view-all.prefix {
    color: gray;
}
```